# CSS Image showing as a broken file

Tags: html, css, eclipse, image

I am trying to add a logo to my webpage. I am using CSS and eclipse. The image shows as a broken image and I am not sure why. The image I am trying to use is in the folder specified : 
Does it need to be added in CSS or can someone please help me to know where I am wrong. Thank you.

```html
<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2 style="text-align: center; color: white;"> New Plan </h2>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="resources/img/logo.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Maybe it's the wrong path - read up on it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: I have added the image to the same path as a different image and the other image works ... @MarcHjorth

Comment: Could you upload that image somewhere? I'll take a look

Comment: check the name of the file and extension, it is key sensitive.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu case sensitive*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wouldn't be a css issue if the browser is showing the broken link icon. That icon means the path to the file is incorrect or it can't retrieve it.

To confirm this, take `resources/img/logo.png` and add it to the end of the URL where your HTML is, excluding any files. For instance, if your URL is `http://example.com/index.php`, you want to make the URL read as `http://example.com/resources/img/logo.png`, without the `index.php`.

You will need to tweak this URL until the image shows up in the browser, since you didn't provide a URL where the HTML is running. When that happens, the URL in the address bar is the one you can use for the image URL.

Answer (score 1):

try to reduce image size with paint.